# How to pass parameter to a c console program using Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, shell, parameters

with other IDE, you can pass parameter to the program via the IDE
(it save times instead of typing hello.c parameter1 parameter2 in the shell)

Is there any way to pass parameters to the program trhough the Xcode IDE instead of just clicking on "RUN" then "CONSOLE" (which provide no arguments to the program)

Thanks

Comment: This is a better, working solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025256/how-do-you-specify-command-line-arguments-in-xcode-4. Worked with Xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "Executables" get info on your binary.

Go to the "Arguments" tab, and add them there.

Comment: This seems a little old, how it's done nowadays? I don't find any "executables" option.