# How do you specify command line arguments in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, command-line-arguments

I just upgraded to Xcode 4 and can't find much documentation on it yet, since it just went gold master. I need to specify a command line argument for testing my application.

The Xcode 3.2 advice doesn't help since everything got moved around.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Command line arguments and environment variables can be set up in the Run section of the scheme editor.
Product -> Edit Scheme... -> Run -> Arguments
(Copy-Paste from the link given by Jano)

Comment: How do you get arguments explicit in a command line Xcode project?
when you run it from the terminal

Comment: (plus1, and thanks) This works, but really I have to go so deep to change parameters for each run?

Comment: In Xcode 7.3 Beta 5: [Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...]

Comment: If argument is a path to file or directory, full path should be given: /Users/MyUser/Documents/Folder/ , relative user directory path (~) is not resolved. It will work when run from command line though.

Comment: @SibbsGambling you just can do ⌘<

Answer (score 33):

The
shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> works too. (Default shortcut)

On Xcode 7 (updated), XCode 10.1

Shortcut : <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>