# XCode 4: file as command argument

Tags: c++, xcode, command-line, command-line-arguments

How do i make a file an argument for a c++ file in Xcode 4? 
now when i run my project i have to do it in terminal with:

```
g++ mainFile.cpp -o main.out < inputfile.txt
```

i want to be able to do the ' < inputfile.txt ' part in XCode so i can use the debugger etc.

in my code i use the inputfile via cin like so:

```
cin>>dim; 

for (int i =0; i<dim; i++) {
    for (int j =0; j<dim; j++) {
        cin>>A[i][j];
    }
}
```

I'm following a beginner course in c++ so this is the way the code has to be. i just want to run it in XCode so badly! Thnx

Comment: I think that you are mixing compilation and running of the application... the `g++` command line above does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Read CedricSoubie's answer to the following Stack Overflow question:

[How do you specify command line arguments in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025256/how-do-you-specify-command-line-arguments-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Just to make it clear, command line arguments can include redirection.  I'm deleting my answer, because I think I was using Xcode 3.