# Thread exception when compiling this basic C++ code in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, thread-exceptions

Everytime I compile this C++ code I get a thread exception I can't understand. What is wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string arg = argv[1];

    if (arg == "-r")
        cout << "First arg is -r" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the exception you obtain it could help.

Comment: "exception when compiling"? You mean a compiler error? Or an exception when you run the program? Please edit your question to include more details, including all errors from the compiler and linker.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it is but [here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mchl6iq81d3mtnz/exception.png) a screenshot of what comes up once its done compiling.

Comment: It is failing on strlen. Are you passing the command line argument while invoking the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to check `argc>=2` before assigning argv[1] to the string `arg`.
Are you sure you are running this program with passing a parameter?

A possible correction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    if(argc<2)
    {
      cerr << "Not enough parameters" << endl;
      abort();
    }

    string arg = argv[1];

    if (arg == "-r")
        cout << "First arg is -r" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's my problem since I was just building and running without adding any parameters.

Comment: Here's a link that can help with setting up command line arguments. [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025256/how-do-you-specify-command-line-arguments-in-xcode-4)