# Sending arguments from terminal to xcode

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to send two arguments to Xcode through terminal.  I've watched some tutorials that had the following steps:

1. Change the directory by typing cd followed by the path of the folder containing the program files.
2. gcc main.c -o randomProgramName
3. ./prog argument1 argument2

My file is a .m file, but replacing the .c the examples uses with a .m doesn't work. I feel like I'm way off.  I also installed the command line tools, hoping it would work, but no dice.

Comment: Do you want to send arguments to a program you're writing **with Xcode**, or are you trying to send arguments to **Xcode itself**?

Comment: @TylerEich to a program i'm writing with xcode.  In the example, terminal should display the result of the program after inputting the arguments.

Comment: if you choose Edit Scheme for your running scheme, there's a tab for arguments.  You can add them there if you want to pass an argument to your program.

Comment: @GW.Rodriguez ya that i'm able to do.  Just trying to learn the steps to do it through terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a program in **Xcode** and want to send arguments to it, there's [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025256/how-do-you-specify-command-line-arguments-in-xcode-4) to help you out.

If you want to send arguments to a compiled Objective-C program in **Terminal**, here's [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146849/accessing-command-line-arguments-in-objective-c) to help with that.

Comment: I came across that same question, which does the same thing.  But I'd like to learn how to do it through terminal.

Comment: @Brosef — So you want to build a program with Xcode, then send arguments to that compiled program from Terminal? Just like you send arguments to any other command line program?

Comment: ya command line arguments.  Like they do in this video http://youtu.be/eSVLr5lI-es?t=11m43s (@11:45) except for a .m file.

Comment: Edited my answer to include both approaches.