# Can I pass parameters to main in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a cross-platform app and use command-line arguments for debug testing and hidden/developer features.
On iOS I still have a `main(argc,argv)` entry-point - is it possible to pass parameters in via XCode? If so, would this only apply to debug builds or would it perhaps depend on the provisioning type in use?

Comment: Yep, as Armand says, there is a way to set command line parms in Xcode.  I use this a fair amount for testing.  Once "live" on a phone, of course, you can't use this, since there's no way for the user to specify parms.

Comment: How do you actually _use_ them though? I pass them to `UIApplicationMain()` but then how does my app-delegate access them?

Comment: @John You can access them by using [NSProcessInfo class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set param at debug time : [How do you specify command line arguments in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025256/how-do-you-specify-command-line-arguments-in-xcode-4)

As you don't manage app lunch in prod, I would like to say don't use this (including in debug except if you tag your code to be there only at debug). more than 1 possible lunch (user click icon, notification incoming....)